# Android emulator: disconnect GPS device from provider

Tags: android, gps, emulation, signals, simulate

I am developing a GPS enabled application on Android. There is no problem with the map display, but I want to test how my code would react to the situation in which the user enters a room, basement or a cave, so that the device would stop receiving any signal. My question is whether I can simulate this programatically or by using the DDMS, and if so, then how?

P.S. The point is to test it all on the emulator, not a real device.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes only come into the emulator when you push them over (e.g., via the Emulator Control tab). If you don't want the emulator to receive fixes, don't send them.